# How to implement :core:testing module using testImplementation in other module?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, gradle, testing

I have :core:testing module, which contains core testing utilities, that should be used in many other features. When I implement :core:testing using

```
testImplementation  project(':core:testing')
```

IDE compiles and sees it, but when running tests, it shows unresolved reference error.

I saw testFixtures solution:

```
testFixtures {
        enable = true
    }
```

but it doesn't work for Kotlin.

Are there any other solutions to get core testing classes in other modules' Unit tests?